# How to set an bitmap image as lock screen wallpaper in my wallpaper app based on Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, wallpaper

I am making a wallpaper app. Here I am taking images from Firebase database. I want to give the users the option to set it as wallpaper and lockscreen. I was able to set the image as wallpaper by the following code

```
            val result:Bitmap=fl_iv.drawToBitmap()
            val wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this)
            try {
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result)
            } catch (ex: IOException) {
                ex.printStackTrace()
            }
```

Here `fl_iv` is the frame layout containing the imageview which showcases the image. I have set up another button there which allows user to use the image as LOCK SCREEN wallpaper.

I tried this code for lock screen but its not working.

```
lock_screen.setOnClickListener {
            val wpManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this)
            val myBitmap: Bitmap = fl_iv.drawToBitmap()
            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    wpManager.setBitmap(myBitmap, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK)
                }
                else{
                    return@setOnClickListener
                }
            } catch (ex: IOException) {
                ex.printStackTrace()

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the [FLAG_LOCK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#FLAG_LOCK) flag in your `wallpaperManager`

`wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK)`

Comment: But FLAG_LOCK can only be used by users of android nougat (api level 24 ) and above. Do you have any idea how to implement it for lower versions? I will use and if and else to check if the user api is 24 and above, if former then i will user FLAG_LOCK otherwise the other method

Comment: Please see the question again. i editted it after i tried a code using FLAG_LOCK but its not working even in API 28. i might be using it wrong. Any suggestions regarding it?

Comment: Do you have the permission SET_WALLPAPER set in your manifest?

Comment: The docs say the API was added in 24, after digging around it looks like it isnt possible on earlier android versions

Comment: yes. i have this line included in manifest   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>

Comment: the same code is working on my phone with android 10(API 29) but its not working in my other phones with android 9 (API 28). I tried in 2 of those . didnt worked in any of them but it worked with my api 29 phone. I thought its supposed to work only in api 24 and above. If my code is incorrect then why its working in my android 10 but not in android 9?

Comment: What devices do you have? I have found sometimes Samsung phones (because of their custom version of Android) dont always work with certain features

Comment: It is working in my Nokia 8.1 device (android 10) but its not working in my brother and mother's  phone . Both of them have Vivo V11 Pro and Vivo S1 (both android 9)

Comment: Noticed the same issue on a Xiaomi MI9 and a POCO M3 both running Android 10. It works fine on a Galaxy Flip 3 running Android 11!?